# PLL turning on when debugging on STM32F767 Nucleo

Tags: debugging, stm32

I have been scratching my head for the past 2 days trying to figure out what is wrong with my very simple UART program on System Workbench for STM32 from STMicroelectronics. For some reason when I set:

```
USART3->BRR = (16000000/9600);  //Sets the baud rate to 9600 with a clock of 16MHz
```

The output on the serial line is rubbish, however when I press the reset button on the board and let it run, I see

```
Hello World
```

As expected. Doing some digging I found out that the source for the system clock is the PLL output (RCC_CFGR register), red arrow on the imagem bellow:

[RCC_CFGR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5w6T.png)

The bits correspondent to the red arrows tells me that the PLL is ON. Analyzing the RCC_PLLCFGR register and inputing the PLLM, PLLN and PLLP parameters togheter with the correspondents prescallers (AHB and APB1) into the CubeMX I arrived at a APB1 bus clock of 48MHz. So I did:

```
   USART3->BRR = (48000000/9600);   //Sets the baud rate to 9600 with a clock of 48MHz
```

And *voilà* doing step by step on the debugger I can see "HELLO WORLD" so the bus clock is 48MHz.
**BUT**, and I press the reset button and leave it running now the output is non-sense. Something on the debugging process is turning on the PLL and using it as the SYSCLK source.

I copied and pasted the code into Keil uVision and there was no problem, debugging and running, so the problem isn't the code itself. I took a look at the startup_stm32.s, core_cm7.h and debug files from SW4STM32 and couldn't find any hint as to why this is happening. Looking in the reference manual [Reference Manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/group0/96/8b/0d/ec/16/22/43/71/DM00224583/files/DM00224583.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00224583.pdf) on page 170 the reset value of RCC_CFGR is 0x0000.0000 so the PLL is TURNED OFF after reset, so something in the debugging is actively setting the PLL ON.

I am using Tera Term to look at the ST-LINK serial port and Digital Discovery from Digilent to confirm what is going on the bus, and both give me even data.

Any ideas?

**Full code:**

```
#include "stm32f767xx.h"
#include "time.h"

/*
 * Function declarations
 */
void uS_Delay(int Time);
void mS_Delay(int Time);
void S_Delay(int Time);
void GPIOAa_Init(void);
void Config_TIM5(void);
void TIM5_IRQHandler(void);
void Enable_TIM5Interrupt(void);
void UART_Config(void);
void UART_Send(int character);

int Delay_End = 0;

int main(void)
{

    GPIOD_Init();

    Config_TIM5();

    Enable_TIM5Interrupt();

    UART_Config();


    int butao = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        UART_Send('H');
        mS_Delay(10);
        UART_Send('E');
        mS_Delay(10);
        UART_Send('L');
        mS_Delay(10);
        UART_Send('L');
        mS_Delay(10);
        UART_Send('O');
        mS_Delay(10);
        UART_Send(' ');
        mS_Delay(10);
        UART_Send('W');
        mS_Delay(10);
        UART_Send('O');
        mS_Delay(10);
        UART_Send('R');
        mS_Delay(10);
        UART_Send('L');
        mS_Delay(10);
        UART_Send('D');
        mS_Delay(10);


    }
}

/*
 * Functions
 */

void uS_Delay(int Time){

    uint32_t Delay = (uint32_t) (unsigned long) (Time*16);

/*  The APB bus cycle period is by default 62.5 nS, defined by the
 *  default bus frequency of 16 MHz. The number of steps to produce
 *  a 1 uS clock is:
 *
 *  Nº Steps = 1uS/62.5nS
 *  Nº Steps = 16
 *
 *  So for a delay of "Time" microseconds the number of steps is:
 *
 *  Delay = Time*16
*/

    TIM5->ARR = Delay;

/*  TIM-ARR value will be the counter boundary to roll over.
 *  The default bus frequency is 16MHz.
 */
    TIM5->CR1 |= 0x09;

/*  TIM5->CR1 is the main basic timer controller, in this situation
 *  the bits 0 and 3 are been set. Those bits enables the counting
 *  itself and the one-shot-mode, respectively. One-shot-mode makes
 *  it so when an update event occurs (overflow, underflow, etc) the
 *  counter stops counting, in other words the bit 0 of TIM%->CR1
 *  is cleared.
 */

    Delay_End = 0;

    while(Delay_End == 0);

    Delay_End = 0;

/*  Delay_End is a flag telling the uS_Delay() function that the
 *  specified delay hasn't finished (Delay_End = 0), so keeps the
 *  PC register stuck on (while(Delay_End == 0)). When the counter
 *  rolls over it generates an interrupt. The handler (TIM5_IRQHandler)
 *  sets this flag and now the program can get out of the while loop
 *  the flag is once again cleared (Delay_End = 0) and the program
 *  resumes.
 */
}

void mS_Delay(int Time){

    uint32_t Delay = (uint32_t) (unsigned long) (Time*16000);

/*  The APB bus cycle period is by default 62.5 nS, defined by the
 *  default bus frequency of 16 MHz. The number of steps to produce
 *  a 1 mS clock is:
 *
 *  Nº Steps = 1uS/62.5nS
 *  Nº Steps = 16.000
 *
 *  So for a delay of "Time" microseconds the number of steps is:
 *
 *  Delay = Time*16.000
*/

    TIM5->ARR = Delay;

/*  TIM-ARR value will be the counter boundary to roll over.
 *  The default bus frequency is 16MHz.
 */
    TIM5->CR1 |= 0x09;

/*  TIM5->CR1 is the main basic timer controller, is this situation
 *  the bits 0 and 3 are been set. Those bits enables the counting
 *  itself and the one-shot-mode, respectively. One-shot-mode makes
 *  it so when an update event occurs (overflow, underflow, etc) the
 *  counter stops counting, in other words the bit 0 of TIM%->CR1
 *  is cleared.
 */

    Delay_End = 0;

    while(Delay_End == 0);

    Delay_End = 0;

/*  Delay_End is a flag telling the uS_Delay() function that the
 *  specified delay hasn't finished (Delay_End = 0), so keeps the
 *  PC register stuck on (while(Delay_End == 0)). When the counter
 *  rolls over it generates an interrupt. The handler (TIM5_IRQHandler)
 *  sets this flag and now the program can get out of the while loop
 *  the flag is once again cleared (Delay_End = 0) and the program
 *  resumes.
 */
}

void S_Delay(int Time){

    uint32_t Delay = (uint32_t) (unsigned long) (Time*16000000);

/*  The APB bus cycle period is by default 62.5 nS, defined by the
 *  default bus frequency of 16 MHz. The number of steps to produce
 *  a 1 S clock is:
 *
 *  Nº Steps = 1S/62.5nS
 *  Nº Steps = 16.000.000
 *
 *  So for a delay of "Time" seconds the number of steps is:
 *
 *  Delay = Time*16.000.000
*/

    TIM5->ARR = Delay;

/*  TIM-ARR value will be the counter boundary to roll over.
 *  The default bus frequency is 16MHz.
 */
    TIM5->CR1 |= 0x09;

/*  TIM5->CR1 is the main basic timer controller, is this situation
 *  the bits 0 and 3 are been set. Those bits enables the counting
 *  itself and the one-shot-mode, respectively. One-shot-mode makes
 *  it so when an update event occurs (overflow, underflow, etc) the
 *  counter stops counting, in other words the bit 0 of TIM%->CR1
 *  is cleared.
 */

    Delay_End = 0;

    while(Delay_End == 0);

    Delay_End = 0;

/*  Delay_End is a flag telling the uS_Delay() function that the
 *  specified delay hasn't finished (Delay_End = 0), so keeps the
 *  PC register stuck on (while(Delay_End == 0)). When the counter
 *  rolls over it generates an interrupt. The handler (TIM5_IRQHandler)
 *  sets this flag and now the program can get out of the while loop
 *  the flag is once again cleared (Delay_End = 0) and the program
 *  resumes.
 */
}

void GPIOD_Init(void){
    int a;

    RCC->AHB1ENR    |= 0x08;            //Enables clock for port D

    a = RCC->AHB1ENR;                   //Small delay

    GPIOD->MODER    |= 0x00020000;
/*
 * Sets output mode for alternate mode for pin PD8
 */

    GPIOD->AFR[1]   |= 0x00000007;
/*
 * Alternate function 7 selected for pin PD8
 */
}

void Config_TIM5(void){
    int a;

    RCC->APB1ENR |= 0x08;           //Enables clock for TIM5

    a = RCC->APB1ENR;               //Small delay

    TIM5->DIER |= 0X01;             //Enables update interrupt
}

void TIM5_IRQHandler(void){

    Delay_End = 1;                  //The specified delay time has ended

    TIM5->SR &= ~(0x01);            //Clears the update event flag
}

void Enable_TIM5Interrupt(void){

    NVIC->ISER[1] = 0x40000;        //Enables interrupt event from TIM5 peripheral

    NVIC->IP[50] = 0x00;            //Sets the priority for the TIM5 interrupt
}

void UART_Config(void){
    int a;

    RCC->APB1ENR |= 0x00040000;     //Enable clock for UART4

    a = RCC->APB1ENR;               //Small delay

    USART3->CR1 |= 0x08;                //Enable the transmitter

    USART3->BRR = (48000000/9600);  //Sets the baud rate to 9600

    USART3->CR1 |= 0x01;                //Enable the USART4

}

void UART_Send(int character){
    USART3->TDR = (character);
}
```

Edit1: I got confused with RCC_CR and RCC_CFGR but the problem is the same.

Edit2: I noticed that the prescalers for APB1 and APB2 buses were also changed.

Edit3: **Workaround** when you start the debugging session press the [icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEgjj.png)(Reset the chip and restart debug session), this button will restart the debug session with a reset. This way the contents of the registers are as expected. I am still on the look for a mre permanent solution.

Comment: you are asking for troubles using "magic" numbers. Use humar readable CMSIS definitions. Everything will start to much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will update the code with your recomendation, but at the end of the day the problem is not related to the code. The only clock registers I am modifying are RCC->APB1ENR and RCC->AHB1ENR. I am not changing RCC_CFGR at all.

Comment: CMSIS is not remotely relevant here.  They are not magic they are hardcoded into the logic so there is no reason to use header files you can use fixed values.   Seems pretty clear that the tool (IDE/environment) is clearly putting the part into either your code or the bootloader.  Your code or the libraries you are calling are not initializing the PLL but the code the tool is running or causing to be run does.  You need in your code to put the part completely in a known state, direct register access, library, whatever you choose

Comment: So yes that means you would set the two lsbits of RCC_CFGR (0x40023808) ideally read-modify-write but you could just set the register to the reset value.  And then the correct thing is to poll bits 3:2 to wait for them to indicate that HSI has been selected.

Comment: If that doesnt work then you can do more of a complete clock setup and configure RCC_CR as well.  Technically someone could have turned off the HSI and you would want to turn it on and wait for it to be ready before selecting it in the RCC_CFGR register.

Comment: as a general rule though either 1) assume post-reset state of the system and dont use any debug environments/tools that will interfere with those assumptions  or 2) if you want to use debug environments then you take more control over the system and put it in a known state and that includes setting up the clocks and divisors when you have configured peripherals that rely on those clocks being at a known speed.

Comment: being a nucleo card you can simply drag and drop your .bin file over and let it run and not have to deal with the interference of debuggers, ides, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer old_timer, I have actually written a very simple piece of code that does exactly what you suggested, all it does is set RCC_CFGR = 0, wait until it has switched and turn off the PLL, what I was interested to know is what was causing this issue, maybe a file or something else.

Comment: it is very inefficient to try to deal with all the possible things that other code can do to you, so you would want to actually use the resets for each block before you do something (if you cant assume your code is running in a post-reset situation).  My bet is they are loading something or booting the internal bootloader which messes with a bunch of things, loading your program into flash, and instead of resetting the board essentially branching to that code with the part in an unknown state.  taht or just press reset every time you load your next program to test it

Comment: Thanks for tips old_timer, do you if there is an option on System Workbench or any eclipse IDE that forces the chip to execute the code out of reset? As there is in Keil of IAR?

Comment: According to *http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0210c/BAJDAGFJ.html* there is a **clock switching** during debug

Comment: Thanks ralf htp, but I don't think this is related to the problem, thats because when I press the button to restart the debug session with a reset, the core is still halted, so it is still using the debug clock as before.

Comment: @ralfhtp it ARM7 which is a prehistoric architecture. Please read first somethingabout it

Comment: @old_timer `assume post-reset state of the system and dont use any debug environments/tools that will interfere with those assumption` please elaborate. How Cortex M debug tools interfere with something in the uC?

Comment: `The core does not allow FCLK or HCLK to be turned off during a debug session. As these are required for the debugger connection, during a debug, they must remain active.` source datasheet : https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/group0/96/8b/0d/ec/16/22/43/71/DM00224583/files/DM00224583.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00224583.pdf, page 1925

Comment: And `SYSCLK` determines `HCLK` and  `FCLK` so `SYSCLK` is also active https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214987/stm32-internal-clocks

Comment: When you are not in debug mode, how do you get your system clock (SYCLK) ? HSE, HSI or PLL ? (datasheet page 152)

Comment: HSI. In my program I am not changing the bits on the RCC_CFGR, however when you first create the project on the IDE it generates a bunch of files:
cmsis_gcc.h 
core_cm7.h 
core_cmFunctions.h 
core_cmInstr.h 
core_cmSimd.h 
system_stm32f7xx.h 
startup_stm32.s
The culprit is probably on one of those, but I couldn't find anything.